# Ruby error: Undefined method 'length'

Tags: ruby, methods

I am using the ruby-docs' website example to determine the longest string length in an array, here is the code I am using :

```
longest = twoOfArray.inject(0)  {|memo,word| memo.length > word.length ? memo : word}
```

According to the docs website, this should tell me the length of the longest word within the array. However, I am getting an error telling me that '.length' is an undefined method. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Ruby version 1.9.3.

Comment: Please edit to give the entire error message and also show what `twoOfArray` looks like.

Comment: Another way is `two_of_array.max_by { |e| e.size }`. [Here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html) is a summary of Ruby's naming convention. Variables are to be lower-case letters, optionally separated by underscores. `size` and `length` are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass first argument in `inject` method.

The right code will be

```
longest = twoOfArray.inject {|memo,word| memo.length > word.length ? memo : word}
```

If there is no arguments, then first element will be initial `memo` object.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't notice what you need in my first answer.

If you need to determine longest string length, you need your block return length. I.e.

```
longest = twoOfArray.inject(0) {|memo,word| memo > word.length ? memo : word.length }
```

Comment: Yes, that seemed to have worked, thanks! I have another question if you dont mind. I need to use the value of that longest variable and put it into this printf : printf "%-*.*s" . The whole line looks like this :  twoOfArray.each {|k, v| puts "%-*.*s" % [longest] + " " + '*'*v }. However, its giving me an error stating " '&' too few arugements (ArgumentError). What am I doing wrong?